# UIView not hidden, but buttons inside of it are?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibutton, hidden

I have a `UIButton` that's text is set to `"Play"`:

```
@IBOutlet weak var boatTypeGamePlayButton: UIButton!
```

When this button is tapped and it's text is set to `"play"`, I want to perform a few functions:

```
@IBAction func boatTypeMatchingGameButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    if boatTypeGamePlayButton.titleLabel?.text == "Play" {
        boatTypeMatchingGameLabel.hidden = true
        boatTypeGameLevelContainer.hidden = false
        boatTypeMatchingGameTitle.text = "Select Level"
        boatTypeGamePlayButton.setTitle("Cancel", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }
```

`boatTypeGameLevelContainer` is a UIView I have with four buttons inside of it.

The problem is that `boatTypeGameLevelContainer` does become visible, which it should, but the buttons inside of it don't. I tried making `IBOutlet`s for the buttons and setting them to become visible in this function, but it didn't change anything.

All the other methods I set are working...

I also have an `else` statement (meaning that the text of `boatTypeGamePlayButton` is set to `"Cancel"`):

```
else {
    boatTypeMatchingGameLabel.hidden = false
    boatTypeGameLevelContainer.hidden = true
    boatTypeMatchingGameTitle.text = "Boat Type Matching Game"
    boatTypeGamePlayButton.titleLabel?.text = "Play"
    boatTypeGamePlayButton.setTitle("Play", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}
```

How can I make sure that the buttons appear? I appreciate any support.

UPDATE: I am adding the buttons using the storyboard, and I'm not changing any properties of them in code.

Comment: Make sure that the views you want to show/hide are all contained within the container view and that the front-to-back ordering is correct.

Comment: Can you provide a picture of what the view is in question

Comment: @soulshined I'm so sorry, I'm new to stack overflow and I need 10 reputation to add an image while I only have 5. If it helps, when I run the simulator the UIView only shows the red background that I set in the storyboard. I added the buttons into the UIView using the storyboard. Thanks for the support.

Comment: No worries. You can always post a link to a picture. Regardless, it's strange behavior for the view to populate but not its contents. That tells me there is something going on with the components and not the code. If your usin auto layout ensure that the constraints are within the view

Comment: @soulshined Ok, I will, but I used the preview to see the buttons and all the buttons were in the correct place. However, I didn't add any constraints to the buttons within the view. Is it required that I add those constraints?

Comment: @CWApps Nope but sometimes when you add them in a certain place without constraints it won't be at that spot when you compile and run because your running on a different device than the xib size is meant for. Sometimes.

Comment: Thanks! I added constraints and now the button is showing. @soulshined

Comment: Phew! @CWApps glad we got you up and running. Nice job.

Comment: @CWApps see my edited answer for proper identification of the issue so users won't have to search for it comments. Also it links you to Autolayout guide by Apple. It's good knowledge and gets you far because as Apple grows, so does the number of devices they make, which means 20 more different sizes of screens you have to worry about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've added the same title to both statements which is causing the confusion. If the text is Play for both instances it will create some issues, as well as cancel. I would suggest segregating the terms.

```
@IBAction func boatTypeMatchingGameButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
if boatTypeGamePlayButton.titleLabel?.text == "Play" {
//some code here
}
else if boatTypeGamePlayButton.titleLabel?.text == "Cancel"{
//do your other code here
} else {
//do something if none of those statements are true
}
```

**EDIT**

If your stating that the view is populating and that your background displays the color you set in storyboard it might be due to lack of auto layout constraints. Usually when you create a storyboard or xib for a specific size and you run on a different size then you specified *without* constraints set for your view and its components they won't compile and run the same way you see in storyboard.

You should review the [Auto Layout Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html) Apple has provided. its extensive and a great resource for your future projects. Auto layout is very intuitive if you learn it properly. Good luck

Comment: @CWApps So can you provide more detail on how you set the buttons in the GameLevelContainer since that's the heart of the issue. How did you add them? Pragmatically/Storyboard? Are you changing any properties or attributes to them before the container is displayed?